# I can't convert data type object to int or str

Tags: python, types, type-conversion

I'm stuck on this problem, have a dataframe with some columns type object and this make it hard to know if there is a missing value and makes unpractical to do some operations.

I tried this:

```py
data_types_dict = {'Remesa':int,
                   'Placa':str,
                   'PlacaR':str,
                   'Cliente':str,
                   'Descripcion':str
                   }
  
data = data.astype(data_types_dict)
```

[image]
And this:

```py
propios.VIAJE = propios.VIAJE.str.replace(',','').astype(float).astype(int)
```

[image]
I'm starting my journey in programming and will appreciate some advice.

Comment: I'm guessing you have a non-integer-like string in your `Remesa` column and so it can't convert the values in that column to `int`?

Comment: Update, I used data['Remesa'] = pd.to_numeric(data['Remesa'], errors='coerce').convert_dtypes() and it works just fine.